# Metodos heredados con diferentes argumentos

Tags: java, java-swing, herencia, polimorfismo

Tengo dos clases que son idénticas y que solo difieren en el argumento que recibe un método. uno recibe una List< A > y el otro un List< B >. Después de eso el código de los métodos es el mismo, hay alguna manera de resolverlo con herencia?

Comment: yo usaría genéricos precisamente para evitar el problema. cuando tengas codigo compartelo y te ayudamos

Comment: Si las listas serán sólo de la clase `A` o de la clase `B`, ¿qué te impide tener dos métodos: **`verbListA(listA List<A>) {}`** y **`verbListB(listB List<B>) {}`**?

Comment: Nada se lo impide, pero comenta Ruslan, usar genéricos sería ideal, por ejemplo: `<T> void verbListAny(listAny List<T>) { ... }`.

Comment: @MauricioContreras ¿usar genéricos sería ideal para dos casos bien específicos? ¿no sería más costoso, por ejemplo en casos de uso masivos y/o concurrentes?

Comment: Hola Maxi21Fi, la pregunta sin código es muy ambigua, cualquier respuesta está bien, cualquier respuesta está mal, te sugiero que la edites, y agregues el código mínimo necesario para entender el contexto y así poder ayudarte, por ejemplo me pregunta... porqué dos clases y no una con dos métodos?.